# I have bundled my app in an .exe but it can't locate the other working files

Tags: python, pyinstaller

So I have created this little script that grabs a file sat next to it and works on it. So far so good. My script has the following:

```py
cwd = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
with open(cwd + '/myfile.csv', newline='') as csv_file:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csv_file)

# rest of the code
```

and when executed as a .py file it works perfectly and it does what it has to do.

The problem comes when I have tried to compile this single file into an executable (both for mac or windows), it just doesn't locate the file 'myfile.csv' sat right next to it.

I have tried to bundle the file with the command `pyinstaller --add-data '/path/to/myfile.csv:.' /path/to/myscript.py`, and yes, it includes the csv in the .spec documentation and bundles it with the rest of the other folders. However, when I execute the program, it keeps saying that it cannot find myfile.csv, while it's trying to reach the root folder in my computer (?)

I might be missing something here, so far all my scripts have worked perfectly using the above code to ensure that the script works on the files in the current working directory, but this doesn't seem to work when it compiles into an .exe.

Is there anything I should be changing in my original code? I am at loss here...

Comment: Your .spec file probably has a small error. It is surprisingly hard to get that right. If you do a folder compile is the file where you expect?

Comment: Yes, this is funny because I compile my script, add the files I need to it and they place the files where they should be. Also the .spec file has the details. Funny enough, the code works on relative paths (precisely because I want it to work on any environment given that all the files are sat together in the same directory), but when it runs on .exe, it's not able to locate it. I'm lost here.

Comment: When you run your compiled executable, the name of the folder lives in an otherwise nonexistent variable `sys._MEIPASS`. I recommend putting that in the path to your file and doing a presence check. If you want to check its value you need to wrap a test like `if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False)` around it.

Comment: what does the status `frozen` mean exactly?

Comment: Bundled into an `.exe`. Pyinstaller puts it there, but I believe other compilers do or did likewise.

Answer (score 0):

When you use [`add-data`](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#adding-data-files) to add your file, it would be extracted in a temp directory and you need to load it from there. So you can use [`sys._MEIPASS`](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/runtime-information.html#run-time-information) to get the temp path and load the file.

```
import os
import sys


def resource_path(relative_path):
    if hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
        return os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, relative_path)
    return os.path.join(os.path.abspath("."), relative_path)


with open(resource_path('./myfile.csv'), newline='') as csv_file:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csv_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, it seemed to work.

Also, I found another solution that works, instead of:

`cwd = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))`

it can be changed to:

`cwd = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])`

But I don't see the logic of it. In any case thanks very much!